# How to correctly display accents from my fb feed with angularjs

Tags: regex, angularjs

I have this feed https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=149375131740957&format=rss20 and i want to display it with angularjs.

I know filters with angularjs but i don't know what is the regexp that i need here

```
app.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        parseFeed : function(url) {
            return $http.jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
        }
    }
}]);
app.filter('cleanit', function () {
    return function (text) {

    text = text.replace(new RegExp(???here???),"à");

    return text;
    }
});
```

html :

```
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds2 | filter:cleanit | limitTo:quantity2">                    
                    <p>
                        <span class="small">{{feed.publishedDate}}</span> 
                        <a href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.title}}</a>
                    </p>                 
                </li>
            </ul>
```

in example, for `"à"`, i have `"&#xe0;"` displayed. What is the regexp for correctly displayed it ?

Comment: nothing to do with regex. probably your html and feed are from different charset, commonly utf8

Comment: What you want is to replace à by &#xe0;?

Comment: @ Quijote Shin : how to add that ?

Comment: fb feed say "utf-8" and i work only in utf8, so...